# Android UI changes at runtime from how it displays in Studio Designer

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm playing around with Android development and am following this [basic tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). I have produced my first Android app ([code is in this repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/HelloAndroid)) and am having an issue controlling its UI/widget layout at runtime.

Even though `activity_main.xml` shows (in the UI Designer) the "**DO IT!**" button as appearing to the right of the `EditText` view/widget:

[image]

Come showtime on the emulator, the button is rendered on top of the `EditText`:

[image]

**Any idea as to why and what I can do so that the button appears to the right of the textfield/`EditText` at runtime (inside the emulator)?**

Comment: Switch to xml view and replace ConstraintLayou with LinearLayout (with android:orientation="horizontal")

Comment: If you are new to android then I will suggest you that start with Relative or Linear Layout

Comment: or to fix this issue follow this guide here in [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not use

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
```

that is only for the layout editor. Check my answer to this question:

[Buttons not in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552260/buttons-not-in-place/)

hope it helps

Comment: Nope this will not work because his view is not Attached with parent also